# c# xml code comment for file reference

Tags: c#, xml-comments

Is there a tag for a file reference in a xml code comment? The file is a sql script file.
Just wondering if there is a better way than something like this

```
///<summary>
///please have a look at c:\code\project1\sql\file1.sql
///</summary>
```

Comment: Do you use these xml comments to generate a html helpfile with sandcastle or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a file URI, this makes it clickable in visual studio:

```
file:///c:/code/project1/sql/file1.sql
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to have a relative path? file://..\..\..\file.sql
That doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JML - Yes, that would be (assuming your file is "c:\code\project\code\source.cs") "file:../sql/file1.sql"

Comment: - sadly, that doesn't work, ive tried /// file:../../Database/EmployeeUploadFileConfiguration_TestDataForFormulaValidation.sql and even tested with a reference to another file in the same folder: /// file://EligibilityCriteriaFormulaTests.cs shame because that would be quite helpful for comments.
intellisense link doesn't work

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it seems to be relative to the devenv.exe (visual studio  executable) location. I'm not sure how I missed that :-s. So it only works for absolute paths.

Answer (score 7):

You can mix in elements from other namespaces, including xhtml, so

```
///<summary>
///please have a look at <a href="file:///c:/code/project1/sql/file1.sql">file:///c:/code/project1/sql/file1.sql</a>.
///</summary>
```

Is allowed, though whether it's made use of well or not depends on what you use to turn the XML into something more readable. Tooltip-use at least in my IDE ignores the tag and displays the text inside (which is what I'd want in a tool-tip).

Of course, it's not much use on a machine that doesn't have the correct c:\code\project1\sql\file1.sql

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used tags are listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.71).aspx. It also mentions that it will process "any tag that is valid XML" so you aren't limited to these.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a things like special tag for file reference in XML. It is meta language without such limitations.