# Create a link in comment that will open another code file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide, shortcut

Is there a way I could include a hyperlink/bookmark in code comments that, when clicked, would open a target code file in the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# xml code comment for file reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403932/c-sharp-xml-code-comment-for-file-reference)

Comment: @pushasha I don't think it's a duplicate of that. The way I read the question, which is a badly written question, is OP wants a link in `//` comments not XML `///` comments.

Comment: @Andrew Gotcha. For some reason my brain automatically defaulted to XML comments. Retracted the flag.

Comment: @Andrew Would be happy to try to improve if you have suggestions. Unfortunately, I think Leandro's suggestion is what I was basically looking for except doesn't work the way I hoped so I'm kind of doubting there's another way to actually open the file for editing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

> //file:C:\Users\Example.cs

Or use the Bookmark :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh.aspx

Comment: Darn... thought the first suggestion was going to work, but it opens it up as black and white and not editable :(